# What do you call doing someone a favor but then talking about it making her feel indebted to you?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

This friend of mine did me a favor but he then talked about it as if I now owe him.

What is the verb for such an behavior?

Example:

> **Alan**: Hey I did that but it was really hard. I usually don't do that for
>   anyone. It took a long time of me.
>   **Bill**: Ow, yeah, now you are ________ . When you do someone a favor, it is not nice to ________ [about it].

I am looking for a verb to fill in the blanks above.

One might call it "bragging" but that is not the word I am looking for. This type of behavior, usually in the form of talking, makes the other party feel as if he or she owes something to the speaker. We do not like people doing it: if someone do us a favor, we like that they do not talk about it as a favor, making it like a big deal, and making us feel as if we owe them. I want a verb for that act.

I found this idiom which means what I want, though the [source](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_do_you_mean_by_casting_a_favor_in_his_teeth) might not be that reliable:

> **To cast a favor in someone's teeth**
>
> > When you cast a favor in someone's teeth you want to make that person
> >     feel that s/he is indebted to you.

But I am still looking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Only because I couldn't tell whether to migrate to [ell.se] or to  [puzzling.se] or to [interpersonal.se] or to [Crossword Puzzles and Word Games](https://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Sasan [These are all just writing-advice requests where everybody gets to cheer for whichever in a long list of copypasta answers best trips their trigger.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160)They don't increase the quality of our site or provide answers for future visitors. Just because you don't know a tactful way to talk about bad people doing bad things to innocents in English doesn't make the matter one that isn't unbefitting a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes. And, that kind of behavior might make you feel guilty. So feel guilty is not the verb for that behavior itself. I am gonna add a not-good word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is really no verb/phrasal verb/etc. for such an act. I really expected much.

Comment: @Mari-LouA By the way, I just added an idiom.

Comment: That idiom seems to be pretty valid, I have never heard of it, but it is listed in [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cast-in-someone-s-teeth) under "tooth" No.15

Comment: Nice edit by the way. Your question is so much better. By the way, you need to change the pronouns in your title, it should be `making you feel indebted to them`

Comment: @Mari-LouA But it is "doing someone a favor", so shouldn't it be "making them feel indebted to you"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Again, but I first said "doing *someone* a favor".

Comment: Look up singular they. Your recent edit is fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67828/discussion-on-question-by-sasan-what-do-you-call-doing-someone-a-favor-but-then).

Comment: @Sasan: Google books claims twice as many written instances of [***throw** it in my teeth*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22throw+it+in+my+teeth%22) as [***cast** it in my teeth*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cast+it+in+my+teeth%22). And [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throw+it+in+my+teeth%2Ccast+it+in+my+teeth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrow%20it%20in%20my%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccast%20it%20in%20my%20teeth%3B%2Cc0) suggests ***cast*** is something of a hangover from C19.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Guilt tripping" was the first thing to come to mind. It means to make someone feel guilty. It's generic and doesn't specify what type of guilt, so it could be used in the context of making someone feel guilty for their efforts in doing them a favor. Keep in mind, it's somewhat more colloquial, and is often spelled with a hyphen (e.g., *guilt-tripping*).

> Alan: Hey I did that but it was really hard. I usually don't do that for anyone. It took a long time of me.
>
> Bill: Ow, yeah, now you are guilt tripping me. When you do someone a favor, it is not nice to guilt trip them for it.

Sources:

- Definition: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guilt-trip
- Examples and Colloquialness: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guilt_trip

Comment: Could you please cite sources for your comments so that your statements are shown to be not just personal opinion but documented fact ?

Comment: Note that the definition of the verb (encourage a state) and that of the noun (the state) do not match precisely. / 'Guilt-trip' is certainly in the right ballpark, but is not restricted to OP's scenario.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The CED did not have an entry for the verb form of the term, only the word used as a noun. Their definition does, however, match the noun entry in the M-W link. I have removed the CED source in any case as the OED link documents of the informality of the term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Per your comment on its not being restricted to the OP's scenario, please see above as my answer points out that it is a more generic term, but that it can be used in that context.